# How to sort a multimap by value being from a struct?

Tags: c++

I have a multimap that contains a tuple as **key** and struct as **value**.
After updating the value of one of the keys, I want to sort the multimap in order to be by DESC.

Here's an example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <cstring>

typedef struct player
{
    player(int position, std::string name, int points) : position(position), playerName(name), points(points) {}

    int             position; // The position where the player is [like scoreboard]
    std::string     playerName; // Player's name
    int             points; // How many points
} PlayerStruct;

typedef std::multimap<std::tuple<int, int, int>, PlayerStruct> PlayerMap;

int main()
{    
    PlayerMap mPlayerMap;

    // Inserting random data for the test
    mPlayerMap.insert(std::make_pair(std::make_tuple(0, 0, 0), PlayerStruct(0, "player1", 30)));
    mPlayerMap.insert(std::make_pair(std::make_tuple(0, 0, 0), PlayerStruct(1, "player2", 20)));
    mPlayerMap.insert(std::make_pair(std::make_tuple(0, 0, 0), PlayerStruct(2, "player3", 10)));

    // Here we going to update the player3
    for (auto it = mPlayerMap.begin(); it != mPlayerMap.end(); ++it)
    {
        const PlayerStruct& players = it->second; // Gets the player struct info
        if (strcmp(players.playerName.c_str(), "player3") == 0) // If the player's name is the same as "player3"
            it->second = PlayerStruct(players.position, "player4", 50); // updates the value to 50 and the player name

        std::cout << "position: " << players.position << ", name: " << players.playerName << ", points: " << players.points << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Expected result:

```
position: 0, name: player4, points: 50 
position: 1, name: player1, points: 30
position: 2, name: player2, points: 20
```

Actual result:

```
position: 0, name: player1, points: 30
position: 1, name: player2, points: 20
position: 2, name: player4, points: 50
```

I searched and find something like **std::sort** or **std::find_if** but nothing worked.

Comment: You don't. the order of a map or multimap is based on the mapped-from key ordering; not the mapped-to value. Change the mapped-to value all you want, it will not change the order of the map itself.

Comment: @WhozCraig What do you recommend as an alternative?

Comment: Not gonna work directly. What you can do instead is to create another map with a desired key and comparator and references/pointers to your original data, e.g. via `reference_wrapper<const PlayerMap::mapped_type>`. Or the data simply has to be copied if that's acceptable. Your call in the end, bottom line is: another data structure is needed, be it a map for auto-sorting or vector that is sorted later.

Comment: An alternative to *what* ? Currently there is no reason to even use a map here. You're not looking up players by tuple key, at least in the given code. Your question should include the *reason* for the current mapping in the first place. That said, an alternative would be a map of sets, where the tuple maps to a set of players, the order of which is based on whatever you want (ex: score, then alphabetic name, whatever). Sets have their own caveats, btw, so beware the misperception of triviality in my description.

Comment: Tangent: `strcmp(players.playerName.c_str(), "player3") == 0` is excessive. Since `playerName` is a `std::string`, you can just do `players.playerName == "player3"`, it knows how to do a comparison to a C-style string.